# Do you hate hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

We have been given the option this year to opt out of this year's Winterbash. The default is opt-in, so if we do nothing or can't decide, we will get hats. However if we decide that we definitely do not want hats, we can make sure the site remains hat-free until at least a year's time.

Comment: Personally, I don't mind either way.  If there was a way to opt-out at the user level, that might be pretty cool, but in the absence of that, I'm not going to stand in the way of those that want it.

Comment: @Frank Individual users can opt out, even if the site has hats.

Comment: They could last year too.

Comment: Then I see no reason to even give us the option; hat haters (hatters, maybe?) can opt-out, and everybody's happy.

Comment: Only a secret hat hater would even ask this question.

Comment: Why only hats? I want horse armor

Comment: [featured] can be removed and [status-completed] added, since the Dec 1 deadline has passed.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

We should allow winterbash. It's a fun little thing that lasts for about 2 months, which users can opt out of if they don't want to take part in it, so there's no reason *not* to do it.

[image: This is going to be us!]

Secondly, I'd like to suggest banning any users who hate hats (That's a bannable offense, right?)

Comment: Wasn't Arqade the first site to actually do a winterbash with hats?

Comment: @Arperum Yes... it started here as a TF2 reference and spread to other sites the next year.

Comment: Incidentally, Winterbash tends to get people to do things they normally wouldn't just in order to get hats.  It's the "bad" kind of gamification.

Comment: @Powerlord This was brought up before. Frankly, discouraging and policing this kind of behaviour is the SE team's job, and I'd assume they'd have learned a thing or two by now. Things like voting rings etc. are actively policed regardless of whether or not there are hats. As for some of the most serious gaming going on, last year that was almost entirely to do with one user.

Comment: Also, why do you have a picture of me wearing my Vintage Towering Pillar of Hats?

Comment: @fredley IIRC there were a couple users involved, most not as completely devoted as the one you are talking about though.

Comment: @Arperum A few people did cross the line from healthy encouragement into unhealthy obsession, but those issues were dealt with. The amount of drama created for non-mods was low. At the end of the day, all the hats go into storage anyway.

Comment: ~blinks~ how long is it since you were an Alot, @wipqozn?

Comment: @shanodin I haven't been an alot in a loooooong time. I was a Wipqalot for awhile (a cross between a turtle and an alot), but I switched from an alot to  Turtle around  year ago.

Comment: @Wipqozn you're definitely not a turtle now, though.

Comment: Is that picture from Sims?

Answer (score 18):

I don't care about hats. But if there is one SE site that should have hats, it's this one.

Answer (score 4):

Yes but this time with game related hats please!

Example, I don't know, like one coming from LoL (not necesarily has to be only the Teemo hat, could be Lulu's), or Doom / Master Chief's helmet, Ryu's bandage, Assassin's Creed hood perhaps?

I mean from well known games :D

Comment: wow no one notices what I wrote

Comment: I suspect the lack of votes is because we don't have any control over what SE decides for that.

Comment: I agree this would be cool, but a) it'd be a pain to implement, and b) We'd be treading into copyright territory (it shouldn't be an issue, but Stack Exchange would at least have to look into it to make sure they aren't treading on any toes)

Comment: How about runescape afro's haha

Comment: But at the end, I'd be great... right?

Comment: ...we had gaming specific hats in the past before the rest of SE decided to steal our hat dash and repurpose it.

Answer (score -6):

Yes, I hate hats.  We should never, ever, ever allow them on the site.  Or at least, not this year.

Comment: *Bring out yer downvotes!*

Comment: You used to be cool.

Comment: @Wipqozn So did you.  Ah, turtle, we knew you well.

Comment: I was never cool.

Comment: This post has 9 upvotes. I think it's time to close the site down entirely.

Comment: Those are (sym)pathetic upvotes

Comment: @fredley It's now 17 upvotes :( god help us all!

Comment: You get to wear an invisible hat.

Answer (score -14):

I think only handsome monkeys on this site should have hats, like me and the guy above me

```
      /\
     /  \
    / /\ \
   / /||\ \
  / / || \ \
 / /  ||  \ \
      ||
      ||
      ||
```

Comment: Downvoted in the hopes that it ends up below @JasonBerkan's, implying that only you and the hat hater should have hats.

Comment: @TrentHawkins thats the spirit!!

Comment: @TrentHawkins haha done